# How to import a python file in a parent directory

Tags: python

If I have the following directory structure:

```
parent/
    - __init__.py
    - file1.py
    - child/
        - __init__.py
        - file2.py
```

In file 2, how would I import file 1?

**Update**:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append(sys.path.append('/'.join(os.getcwd().split('/')[:-2])))
>>> import parent
>>> ImportError: No module named parent
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to specify parent and it needs to be on the sys.path

```
import sys
sys.path.append(path_to_parent)
import parent.file1
```

Comment: I tried this [ see revised question above ], but still seem to be getting the same problem.

Comment: Is that a typo in your tree structure, you need `__init__.py`, not `__.init__.py`

Comment: -1: sys.path hacks shouldn't be used in this case. Ordinary absolute/relative imports are enough

Answer (score 5):

You still need to mention the parent, since they're in different namespaces:

```
import parent.file1
```

Comment: Even when I mention the parent I still get the same import error.

Comment: @David542 Obviously, parent directory needs to be in sys.path.

Comment: @Jiri I tried this [ see revised question above ], but still seem to be getting the same problem.

Comment: @David542 try doing `sys.path.append('/Users/Premiere_032/Desktop')` instead

Comment: @JacobAbrahams unfortunately, same result.

Comment: @David542 You have misnamed your __init__.py file. It shouldn't be named with ending underscores! correct: _ _ i n i t _ _ . p y

Answer (score 0):

There is a whole section about Modules on the Python Docs:

Python 2:
http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html

Python 3:
http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/modules.html

In both see section 6.4.2 for specific imports of parent packages (and others too)

Answer (score -1):

Here's something I made to import anything. Of course, you have to still copy this script around to local directories, import it, and `use` the path you want.

```
import sys
import os

# a function that can be used to import a python module from anywhere - even parent directories
def use(path):
    scriptDirectory = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])  # this is necessary to allow drag and drop (over the script) to work
    importPath = os.path.dirname(path)
    importModule = os.path.basename(path)
    sys.path.append(scriptDirectory+"\\"+importPath)        # Effing mess you have to go through to get python to import from a parent directory

    module = __import__(importModule)
    for attr in dir(module):
        if not attr.startswith('_'):
            __builtins__[attr] = getattr(module, attr)
```