# Python package import from parent directory

Tags: python, import, package, importerror

I've the following source code structure

```
testapp/
├─ __init__.py
├─ testmsg.py
├─ sub/
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ testprinter.py
```

where `testmsg` defines the following constant:

```
MSG = "Test message"
```

and `sub/testprinter.py`:

```
import testmsg

print("The message is: {0}".format(testmsg.MSG))
```

But I'm getting `ImportError: No module named testmsg`

Shouldn't it be working since the package structure? I don't really want to extend sys.path in each submodule and I don't even want to use relative import.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @SimeonVisser running `python sub/testprinter.py`, but also `python testprinter.py` within `sub` directory doesn't work.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It all depends on which script you **run**. That script's path will be added to python's search path automatically.

Make it the following structure:

```
TestApp/
├─ testapp/
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ testmsg.py
│  ├─ sub/
│  │  ├─ __init__.py
│  │  ├─ testprinter.py
├─ README
├─ LICENSE
├─ setup.py
├─ run_test.py
```

Then run `TestApp/run_test.py` *first*:

```
from testapp.sub.testprinter import functest ; functest()
```

Then `TestApp/testapp/sub/testprinter.py` could do:

```
from testapp.testmsg import MSG
print("The message is: {0}".format(testmsg.MSG))
```

More good hints [here](http://as.ynchrono.us/2007/12/filesystem-structure-of-python-project_21.html);

Comment: may it depend on the fact that I didn't generate a setup.py file? What I mean is that I followed the python package structure but I didn't generate installation method, assuming it could also work without having to `setup.py install` it.

Comment: @CodeShining, no it doesn't matter. I only included the `setup.py` in the example for clarity. What really matters, as I said in the first paragraph of the answer, is **which file you're running in first place**. If you start (run) a file inside the package, it won't see the package. So it's a good practice to have your main script (the one you **run**) outside the package.

Answer (score 15):

Use relative import like below

```
from .. import testmsg
```

Comment: but being a package shouldn't it be working as expected? I wouldn't use relative if it's expected to work

Comment: CodeShining, look at Dido's decision for python 3.5 PEP-328 for standard. [link](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision)

Comment: `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

Comment: @CameronHudson the neighboring folder also needs to be a package (i.e. have its own `__init__.py`)

Answer (score 14):

For people who still have this same problem. This is how I solve mine:

```
import unittest 
import sys
import os

sys.path.append(os.getcwd() + '/..')

from my_module.calc import *
```

Comment: This save my day, I have been searching my whole but no result, thanks :)

Comment: cwd is not always the actual parent of the script running and the running script is what is your current top level. if you want to meddle with sys.path, then you should use parent of the `__file__` instead of parent of cwd

Comment: as @SoulReaver points out, better do `sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir))` (or use the `pathlib` module in Python3).

Answer (score 11):

This question has the answer - dynamic importing:

[How to import a python file in a parent directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078287/how-to-import-a-python-file-in-a-parent-directory/10078468#comment17421554_10078468)

```
import sys
sys.path.append(path_to_parent)
import parent.file1
```

Here's something I made to import anything. Of course, you have to still copy this script around to local directories, import it, and `use` the path you want.

```
import sys
import os

# a function that can be used to import a python module from anywhere - even parent directories
def use(path):
    scriptDirectory = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])  # this is necessary to allow drag and drop (over the script) to work
    importPath = os.path.dirname(path)
    importModule = os.path.basename(path)
    sys.path.append(scriptDirectory+"\\"+importPath)        # Effing mess you have to go through to get python to import from a parent directory

    module = __import__(importModule)
    for attr in dir(module):
        if not attr.startswith('_'):
            __builtins__[attr] = getattr(module, attr)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```py
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

from my_module import *
```