# Importing modules from a "sub-sub-directory" in Python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a directory tree which looks like the following (visualized using [tree](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-show-directory-structure-command-line/)):

```
.
├── __init__.py
└── testsubdir
    ├── __init__.py
    └── testsubsubdir
        ├── __init__.py
        └── __init__.pyc
```

The `__init__.py` in the main directory contains the command `import testsubdir`, and the `__init__.py` in `testsubdir` contains `import testsubsubdir`. What I notice is that this works in Python 2.7, but not in Python 3.5:

```
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~/Documents/Scratch/testdir$ python __init__.py
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~/Documents/Scratch/testdir$ python3 __init__.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import testsubdir
  File "/home/kurt/Documents/Scratch/testdir/testsubdir/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import testsubsubdir
ImportError: No module named 'testsubsubdir'
```

I'm working on 'translating' some source code from Python 2 to Python 3 which contains an import statement similar to the above. What would be the best way to make this work in Python 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11393538/6394138) suggests using a relative import:

In top level `__init__.py`:

```
from . import testsubdir
```

In `testsubdir/__init__.py`:

```
from . import testsubsubdir
```

Comment: Does this work for you? I get `ValueError: Attempted relative import in a non-package` for the line `from . import testsubdir`.

Comment: @KurtPeek I tested by putting the top level `__init__.py` in a package `testdir` and doing `import testdir`.

Comment: @KurtPeek If you want to feed the top level `__init__.py` to python3 directly, then keep the `import` statement in it as `import testsubdir`.