# relative imports in python-3x

Tags: python-3.x

```
> Project
>> __init__.py
>> moduleA
  >>> __init__.py
  >>> file_1.py
>> moduleB
  >>> __init__.py
  >>> file_2.py
```

I have the following Directory Structure for a Python Project. I want to `import` `file_1.py` into `file_2.py` . How can I do so ?

I tried inserting the given below snippet in `file_2.py`:

```
from ..moduleA import file_2
```

But I keep Getting this error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I also tried this

```
from Project.moduleA import file_1
```

This method works in the `PyCharmIDE` but won't work in `VSCode` wherein I get this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Project'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python package import from parent directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393492/python-package-import-from-parent-directory)

Comment: Can't I just use `relative importing`? I have seen a lot of `GitHub repo's` using `relative importing` and it works fine. I don't know whats wrong in my case