# Import .py file from parent directory

Tags: python, import

I wanted to import a file from another folder into another file in the same root folder.

Directory list:

```
ROOT/
    resource/
        console_log/
            __init__.py (empty)
            file1.py
        libs/
            __init.py__ (empty)
            function.py
    __init__.py (empty)
```

I tried using this code in `resource/console_log/file1.py`:

```
from resource.libs.function import function_name
```

It just doesn't work. Returns this error:

> No module named 'resource'

If I use this code instead

```
from ..libs.function import function_name
```

It gives me this:

> attempted relative import with no known parent package

How can I solve?

Is there any way to fix it without using the `sys`?

**EDIT:**

I "fixed" the problem by moving all the files directly to the libs folder thus removing the resource folder. Except that if from `libs/file1.py` I want to import a function present in the `main.py` file I get the same error

New folder structure:

```
ROOT/
    libs/
        __init__.py
        file1.py
        file2.py
        function.py
    logs/
        debug.log
    __init__.py
    main.py
```

If I use this code in the `libs/file1.py` file, it works correctly (only if I start it from the `main.py` file)

```
# file1.py
from libs.function import function_name
```

But if in `libs/file2.py` I want to recall a variable present in the `main.py` file, it returns me an error

```
# file2.py
from main import data

# ERROR
No module named 'main'
```

If he doesn't give me this error he gives me another one
`attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: This asnwer could help you problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/11393586/14466874

Comment: @martineau Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/a/43476575/674039  Why reopened?

Comment: @wim: Because I don't think your answer to the other question is platform-independent — and even if you think it now is, it's not clear that something that changes an environment variable temporarily is a solution to this problem (because scripts are not always executed through a shell).

Comment: Then you didn't read the answer fully, or you've glossed over the part which said an installer (setup.py or pyproject.toml) is needed in order to place the code into site-packages.

Comment: ..... aaaaand now the duplicate PYTHONPATH answers are coming in.  :)

Comment: @wim: There's no installers involved _here_. And the fact that others are making the same assumptions as you proves nothing.

Comment: How do you use `resource/console_log/file1.py`? Do you run it as a script? If so, what is the working directory? Or do you import it as a module in another file?

Comment: Well the code needs to get on `sys.path` somehow, this is a pretty clear dupe of [ImportError: No module named <something>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43476575/674039) isn't it?  The other issue with "attempted relative import with no known parent package" is what you get when you attempt to run a submodule within a package as a script, that one is well covered over on [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14132789/674039).

Comment: @mkrieger1 I run the script directly from visual studio code

Answer (score 0):

I think your `PYTHONPATH` isn't set correctly.  You can either export it or run your program with it set as expected for the single command.  The following will set the `PYTHONPATH` for the single command execution:

```
PYTHONPATH=./:$PYTHONPATH python resource/console_log/file1.py
```

Comment: I honestly think it is set correctly, also because if I go to the `ROOT/main.py` file I can import the file in the `libs/function.py`